# Is using expos intern filesystem API a better solution than the react-native-fs when the app will be published on Playstore / Appstore?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, filesystems, expo

I am fairly new to AppDevelopment with react-native and I am using expo. I have a hard time writing to the file-system, especially with `react-native-fs`. So I heard about `the expo-file-system`and that it might be easier to use instead.

However, I am not sure if the  API will be available when I transfer the App to the Playstore / AppStore - what are the downsides of each one? And what would be a better solution in my case?

My use case is just writing User-Data into a json file, so nothing fancy